# In Angular: How to keep token saved and user logged in when opened new tab and pasted url to it

Tags: angular

I have a code which will save valid token from API with a life span in session storage, hence till user is having valid token system keeps working. I the user do not have token then with help of auth guard user will be redirected to login page. For this type of configuration I need to have a way where, if user copies the URL from logged in page and past on new then also user should be in system with valid log in. Because for session storage new tab will not have session data stored in it so user is logged out. Hence can any one suggest a way to satisfy this requirement?

--App module code

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [CommonService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent,]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

--app routing module

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { MainLayoutComponent } from "./shared/layout/app-layouts/main-layout.component";
import { AuthLayoutComponent } from "./shared/layout/app-layouts/auth-layout.component";
import { AuthGuard } from "./core/guards/auth.guard";

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "",
        component: MainLayoutComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            {
                path: "",
                redirectTo: "dashboard/analytics",
                pathMatch: "full"
            },
            {
                path: "dashboard",
                loadChildren: "./features/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule",
            }            
        ]
    },

    {
        path: "auth",
        component: AuthLayoutComponent,
        loadChildren: "./features/auth/auth.module#AuthModule"
    },
    { path: "**", redirectTo: "miscellaneous/error404" }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

--Auth guard code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private router: Router) {}
    canActivate(){
        if (sessionStorage.getItem('auth_token')) {
            return true;
        }        
        this.router.navigate(['/auth/login']);
        return false;
    }
}
```

--Service code which saves token from API call

```
login(model: any): Observable<any> {
        let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        return this.http.post(API URL, model, { headers: headers }).pipe(
            map((res: any) => {
                var obj = jwt_decode(res.responseObject);
                sessionStorage.setItem('auth_token', obj);
                return true;
            }), catchError((res: any) => {
                return Observable.throw(res.error.error);
            })
        );
    }
```

--Model to pass for API with valid credentials

```
export class LoginModel {
    constructor(
        public username: string,
        public password: string
    ) { }
}
```

Comment: Can you use cookie instead of session storage? Cookie is available between tabs

Comment: What you describe is a need of `localStorage` instead of `sessionStorage`. Can you use it ?

Comment: Please consider using local storage instead of session storage

Comment: Sure let me try out